# How to configure vm login with Azure AD credentials (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine

I have been trying to configure login with Azure Credentials for a Windows Server , I followed up this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows

I can see that extension is installed , however once I tried to login in received this error :

[Logon Faile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sagp.png)

I see some advices about this but still having the issue :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#unauthorized-client

Alreday tried using AzureAD/UPN but did not work.

Do I need to do Azure AD Join to this server for being able to use this extension for AzureADLogin ? Or I need to do Azure AD Join to my personal computer that is trying to connect to this vm via RPD ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do either Azure AD registered (starting Windows 10 20H1), Azure AD joined or hybrid Azure AD joined to your personal computer that is trying to connect to this Azure VM. See the [Supported Azure regions and Windows distributions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#supported-azure-regions-and-windows-distributions).

> Remote connection to VMs joined to Azure AD is only allowed from
> Windows 10 PCs that are either Azure AD registered (starting Windows
> 10 20H1), Azure AD joined or hybrid Azure AD joined to the **same
> directory** as the VM.

For more reference, you may want to know [find the Azure AD Join Type](http://dsregcmd%20/status) with the command `dsregcmd /status`.